# Getting a specific contour from ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting

How can I extract a single contour line of a `ListContourPlot`?

Below is a minimal example:

```
ListContourPlot[Table[{x=RandomReal[{-2,2}],y=RandomReal[{-2,2}],Sin[x y]},{1000}]
    ,Contours->6
    ,MeshFunctions->{#3&},Mesh->{{0.5}},MeshStyle->Directive[Opacity[1,Red],Thick]
    ,PlotLegends->Automatic]
```

[image]

I'd like to get the red contour line at `z = 0.5` (as an example) of different `ListContourPlot`s and stack them in a new coordinate grid using `Show`.

Comment: Why not use the settings `Contours -> {0.5}, ContourShading -> None`?

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. Sometimes, I seem to think too complicated...

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less can you post it as an answer, such that this can be flagged as solved by @DPF?

Comment: @Glad, not at a computer now, and this is a question that needs a picture as part of the answer. Maybe you or the OP can write one on my behalf?

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less did that, any comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use contours and contourStyles to specify thresholds and colors.

```
contours = {0.2, 0.5, 0.9}
contourStyles = {Red, Green, Blue}
ListContourPlot[
 Table[{x = RandomReal[{-2, 2}], y = RandomReal[{-2, 2}], 
  Sin[x y]}, {1000}], 
 Contours -> contours, 
 ContourStyle -> contourStyles, 
 ContourShading -> None, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Multi-Threshold ContourPlot]

You could combine them using Show like:

```
plots = ListContourPlot[
 Table[{x = RandomReal[{-2, 2}], y = RandomReal[{-2, 2}], 
  Sin[x y]}, {1000}], 
 Contours -> {contours[[#]]}, 
 ContourStyle -> {contourStyles[[#]]}, 
 ContourShading -> None, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic] & /@ Range[3]
Show[plots]
```

to generate them separated and combine them later.

Comment: Well-done! :) ${}$

Comment: Especially the second part is what I wanted. The application is the comparison of the same contour heigths between different measurements of a 2D set point field.